# I need to select all records from the table without the record which I selected by subquery, but it return all records again

Tags: sql

```
Select * from Loan
where EXISTS (Select * from Loan where Loan_No != 'A1234')
```

Comment: When EXISTS, you need a correlated subquery.

Comment: As a general rule, I think that any question that does not feature descriptive text in the body is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Questions here need to be useful for other readers, and in order to be useful, they need to contain some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh?  Why aren't you just using this?

```
select l.*
from loan l
where loan_no <> 'A1234';
```

Your query either returns ALL rows in the table or NONE of them.  Why?  Because `exists` returns true if the subquery returns any rows and false otherwise.  There is no correlation to the outer query, so the condition is the same for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select the records with loan_no != 'A1234' just use this :

```
select * from loan where loan_no != 'A1234'
```

and if you want to select records without records that you selected in subquery use this:

```
select * from loan where loan_no not in (select loan_no from loan where XXX)
```